# Namespace causing PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class Not Found error

Tags: php

I have three libraries installed via composer.

```
https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
https://github.com/openai-php/client
```

and I have tried to use it in my index.php file like

```
<?php
    namespace PhpImap;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    .....
?>
```

Its giving me error on this line

```
$client = OpenAI::client($yourApiKey);
```

called

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "PhpImap\OpenAI" not found in /home/myuser/mydomain.com/dashboard/crons/reply/reply.php:216
```

My composer.json is like below

```
{
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php-imap/php-imap": "^5.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.8",
        "openai-php/client": "^0.6.4",
        "symfony/http-client": "^6.3",
        "nyholm/psr7": "^1.8"
    }
}
```

If I remove Namespace PhpImap from 2nd line, its work but its required for my imap function. **I think that namespace conflict with OpenAi library**. I do not getting idea to resolve the issue. Let me know if someone can help me for solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read through [the explanation of namespaces in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/namespace) to understand the key concepts.

One way to think about it is that the full name of a class can have parts separated by `\`, and all the namespace machinery is just ways of referring to the class by shorter names. Simplifying a bit, there are two ways that happens:

- The `namespace` keyword specifies a default prefix for all classes in a particular file
- The `use` keyword specifies particular exceptions to that rule, where a short name refers to something with a different prefix

Importantly, these two rules take priority over looking for a class with no namespace prefix at all. To say you *don't* want any prefix to be added, you have to make a name "fully qualified" with a leading `\`.

In your case, the full name of the class you want to use is `OpenAI` with no prefix, but you've told PHP to add the prefix `PhpImap` by default, so it's looking for `PhpImap\OpenAI`. You need to either:

- Specify it as `\OpenAI`
- Add a `use` statement at the top of the file, `use OpenAI;` to tell the compiler that you want `OpenAI` on its own to refer to the class throughout the file

Answer (score 1):

The [`OpenAI`](https://github.com/openai-php/client/blob/main/src/OpenAI.php) class is not namespaced, which means that you need to prefix it with a `\` when you use it:

```
$client = \OpenAI::client($yourApiKey);
```

Comment: Thanks, It have solved the issue. Thanks!